# IBM Worklight - How does Worklight detect the project version?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

Recently we'd updated our Worklight platform with the latest Fixpack (6.1.01) and everything works fine after the update.

However although we had check in all our files into our SVN repository, when we check out a fresh copy of project, the eclipse Worklight plugin will still perform an upgrade to the project.

Is there a Worklight platform version control in the project folder that we missed out and didn't commit to the repository? or is there extra setting that we need to apply before checking into the SVN repo?

Any clues will help, thank you.

**EDIT**

Below is the print screen taken from the SVN Repository browser in eclipse. We use Windows environment for development. The `.settings` folder is inside the repo.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

After inspecting the `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file in the `.settings` folder, i notice that there's this line of properties that are not updated in the repo:

```
wl_version=6.1.0.00.20131219-1900
```

Is it this line that is causing the problem?

Comment: After upgrading the project (opening Eclipse and start working), does the version change to 6.1.0.01-xxxxxxxx ?

Comment: Yes it did. I'm hoping to have some confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the question with the files/folders you *did* commit to SVN.

Additionally, make sure to setup your PC/Mac to display hidden files and folders and see that you did not miss those.

Specifically, there is a `.settings` folder (`.` denotes a hidden folder in Mac) that also contains a `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file.

I'd be interested to see the result of an import of a project that *does* contain this folder and this specific file.

[image]

Comment: I'd updated my post with a screen shot of the repository browser

Comment: Thanks to @Idan pointers, am able to resolve this by putting the correct value in the `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file